# Scraping Interactive Line Charts with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, mouseover

I would like to know how to extract the data that popped up when the mouse hovers over a certain time frame inside a graph panel.

The website is
https://app.truflation.com/

[Data Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlMpS.png)

I tried Use Selenium to webscrape the data that popped up. There was a solution from https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-interactive-charts-with-python-2bc20a9c7f5c and https://youtu.be/lTypMlVBFM4 but the difference here is I cannot capture the XPATH of the popup message.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/hudso/OneDrive/Documents/UST course/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://app.truflation.com/")
datas = driver.find_element_by_class_name('overlay')
for data in datas:
    Date = data.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="trufrate-timeframe"]/g[2]/text[1]').text
    Inflation = data.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="trufrate-timeframe"]/g[2]').text
    print(Date,Inflation)
```

I tried many different versions and this one seems to be closer. I am yet to print Date and Inflation, so not yet applied it to dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @h0204663 the data you need is dynamically added - see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ejtR.png) - I think you need to [edit] your question and add what are the exact results you want (*you want only 1 data from that chart or the whole values used on the chart?*).

Comment: @h0204663 the data you need is dynamically added - see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ejtR.png) - I think you need to [edit] your question and add what are the exact results you want (*you want only 1 data from that chart or the whole values used on the chart?*).

Comment: I want to extract the date and the inflation rate and put them into a dataframe. Thanks